# HttpClient not getting same CookieContainer as HttpWebRequest

Tags: cookies, windows-8, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I have an application in WPF that I use HttpWebRequest to Post a login in a 3rd party website, the HttpWebRequest.GetResponse works pretty well and
I get the correct cookies that I need.

The code working fine is:

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();
string postData = "login-passaporte=email@yahoo.com.br&senha-passaporte=PASS&urlRetorno=http://sportv.globo.com/site/cartola-fc/&usar-sso=true&botaoacessar=acessar";
byte[] data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(postData);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://loginfree.globo.com/login/438");

request.Timeout = 100000;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Then, when I try to port this code for an Windows 8 Store App, using HttpClient, my code do not return the correct logged cookie (9 cookies on code above, only 1 cookie below, same cookie that I get when use invalid username or password)

```
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

string postData = "login-passaporte=email@yahoo.com.br&senha-passaporte=PASS&urlRetorno=http://sportv.globo.com/site/cartola-fc/&usar-sso=true&botaoacessar=acessar";
HttpContent content = new StringContent(postData, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
handler.UseCookies = true;
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(1000000000);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)");

var response = await client.PostAsync("https://loginfree.globo.com/login/438", content);
```

Looks to me that the HttpClient.PostAsync is not sending the correct information to the page but I try almost everything that I know and can't figure out what is it.

PS.: This username and password is just an working account for tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to pass the Content-Type to my HttpContent.

To fix my code, I just need to add another parameter to the StringContent constructor.

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(postData, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```